# Flask, Python: File is not saving in the folder "images"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to create new folder with name "images" and save the file [Which is coming from upload.html] in the "images" folder. My issue is, folder is generating but file is not saving into the folder. Please see the attached code below.

```
upload.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Convert csv to JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="{{url_for('upload')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="upload" accept="image/"/>
<input type="submit" /></form>

</body>
</html>
```

on the console out put is:

```
E:/images
<FileStorage: u'I-94.pdf' ('application/pdf')>
('Accept incoming file:', u'I-94.pdf')
E:/images/I-94.pdf

  File "E:\datamining\tryproject\convert.py", line 32, in upload
    upload.save(destination)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'save'
```

python code is shown below

```
convert.py

import os

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_from_directory

__author__ = 'praveen'

app = Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("upload.html")


@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():

    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, '/images')
    print(target)
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    for file in request.files.getlist("upload"):
        print(file)

        filename = file.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print("Accept incoming file:", filename)
        print(destination)
        upload.save(destination)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=4555, debug=True)
```

Comment: `upload` is the name of your view function instead of a file object.

Comment: @stamaimer thankyou so much for the suggestion. It is working fine now.

Comment: @eyllanesc i made the correction and posted the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
convert.py

import os

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_from_directory

__author__ = 'praveen'

app = Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("upload.html")


@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():

    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, '/images')
    print(target)
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    for file in request.files.getlist("upload"):
        print(file)

        filename = file.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print("Accept incoming file:", filename)
        print(destination)
        file.save(destination)   //i made change here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=4555, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove a slash from this:

```
target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, '/images')
```

So it's going to be:

```
target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images')
```